# How to pass form values from child component to parent in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to pass the values inside a form to the parent component and then display the values in other child component.

I tried using states and props but it seems like I am missing something. It tells me that you are trying to use props on undefined value. I am not able to figure out where. I tried googling and did some search. nothing works as of now.

Here is my code:

Parent :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      age:"",
      gender:""
    };
  }

  changeValue(name,age,gender) {
    this.setState({
      name: name,
      age:age,
      gender:gender
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormView changeValue={this.changeValue.bind(this)}/>
        <DisplayView name={this.state.name} age= {this.state.age} gender= {this.state.gender}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Child 1 :

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      handleChange(e){
        this.props.changeValue(e.target.name.value,e.target.age.value,e.target.gender.value);
      }

  render() {

    return <form>
        <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name"  />
        </label>
        <label>
        Age:
        <input type="number" name="age"   />
        </label>
        <label>
        Gender:
        <select name="gender" >
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
        </label>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
   </form>

  }
```

Child2 :

```
 render(){
        return (
          <div>
             <p>{this.props.name}</p> 
             <p>{this.props.age}</p>
             <p>{this.props.gender}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
```

I am expecting to display the form values of child1 in child2.

I am getting an undefined value error.

Comment: You can create prop `onChange` with function in your child component, the handler will update parent component and called in child component.

Comment: ``e.target.name.value`` doesn't refer to the name input. You have to use refs for that or, as jcubic says, use the onChange handler and ``e.target.value`` for each prop

Comment: @Hafsa, your component should work as expected as long as you use an onSubmit listener on the form tag. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: Thanks jcubic and Cody Swan. I will try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You component works fine if we define an `onSubmit` listener and handler for the form. We also need to call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the page from refreshing, that way the values actually get passed up to parent component when you call  `this.props.changeValue()`

See codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-ellis-76bdv

```
import React from "react";

class FormView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleChange(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.changeValue(
      e.target.name.value,
      e.target.age.value,
      e.target.gender.value
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" name="name" />
        </label>
        <label>
          Age:
          <input type="number" name="age" />
        </label>
        <label>
          Gender:
          <select name="gender">
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default FormView;
```

Comment: @HafsaMushtaq You're very welcome, I could go through the exercise of showing you how to implement the other suggestions as well, if you'd like, but I find this to be the cleanest. Would you consider marking my solution as the answer. :)

Comment: Thankyou @Christopher. I did make your solution an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get an element in React you can use refs on each input or one on the form https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleChange(e){
    console.log(this.name.value, this.age.value, this.gender.value);
    this.props.changeValue(this.name.value, this.age.value, this.gender.value);
  }

setName = (name) => {
   this.name = name;
}

setAge = (age) => {
   this.age = age;
}

setGender = (gender) => {
   this.gender = gender;
}

render() {

return <form>
    <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" ref={this.setName} name="name"  />
    </label>
    <label>
    Age:
    <input type="number" ref={this.setAge} name="age"   />
    </label>
    <label>
    Gender:
    <select ref={this.setGender} name="gender" >
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: I will go through the concept of refs